# Try to get a UIImage from Asset Library Url

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to get a UIImage Object from a given Asset-Library-Url. I want to make function doing this for me.
The given Url is: `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=46811D66-DBB4-46D9-BBA2-0CF0D58FC7AD&ext=JPG` I tried it with the following approach :

```
var url = NSURL() // url = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=46811D66-DBB4-46D9-BBA2-0CF0D58FC7AD&ext=JPG" got it from another scene
var asset = ALAssetsLibrary()
var tempImage = UIImage()
tempImage = getUIImagefromAsseturl(url)



func getUIImagefromAsseturl (url: NSURL) -> UIImage {

    asset.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: {
        (asset: ALAsset!) in
        if asset != nil {
            var assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
            var iref = assetRep.fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue()
            var image =  UIImage(CGImage: iref)
            return image

        }
        }, failureBlock: {
            (error: NSError!) in

            NSLog("Error!", nil)
        }
    )


}
```

But I always get an error saying that : 
*Cannot invoke 'assetForURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, resultBlock: (ALAsset!) -> _, failureBlock: (NSError!) -> _)'*

Can anybody please tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to return your image from within the `resultBlock`, but that block is of type `(ALAsset!) -> Void` so you cannot return the image from inside the block.  While Xcode's Swift error could be more clear here, I bet that because you are trying to return a UIImage from your `resultBlock`, the compiler has inferred the type of your provided `resultBlock` to be `(ALAsset!) -> UIImage`, which does not match the expected type of `(ALAsset!) -> Void`.

Because of the way `assertForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` works (both completions return type `Void`), you will never be able to return anything from either of the completion blocks.  You will need to pass the code for displaying or otherwise handling the image into `assertForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` as part of the `resultBlock`.

Because of this, you will not be able to return the image from your function `getUIImagefromAsseturl:`, so you'll want to remove the return type `UIImage`.

If you do plan to display the image, it would be best to update the UI from within the main thread.  This is pretty easy:

```
func getUIImagefromAsseturl (url: NSURL) {

    asset.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: { asset in
        if let ast = asset {
            let assetRep = ast.defaultRepresentation()
            let iref = assetRep.fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue()
            let image = UIImage(CGImage: iref)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                // ...Update UI with image here
            })
        }
    }, failureBlock: { error in
        println("Error: \(error)")
    })
}
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, but changing the code to exactly your code, still throws the same error.

Comment: I updated the code again.  Try it out.  It's a little further from yours but functionally the same as my last edit.  This one is verified to work in Xcode 6.3.1. Instead of testing for nil in the `resultBlock` like you did, I did a standard Swift `if let` binding. It seems to have placated Xcode.

Comment: Also I used `{ asset in ... }` instead of `{ (asset: ALAsset!) in ... }` when defining the `resultBlock` (and likewise the `failureBlock`). This lets Xcode just use inferred typing when processing the blocks, although it really shouldn't make a difference. Xcode + Swift can still be touchy sometimes.

Comment: my image path is  : /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0250.JPG         Can i get the image using asset library